# How to add image to imagelist from database and show them on listview

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview, imagelist

I need to add all image of my books in SQL Server database to the imagelist and show them on listview, but when I run the program, it shows the first image and repeats it on another images but the id of the images is changing I don't know what the problem is.

[Image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l1sT.png)

[Image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOs7Q.png)

And this is the code:

```
MySqlConnection msc = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=listv;uid=root;");

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id,image from books");
msc.Open();

listView1.Clear();

ImageList images = new ImageList();
images.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

listView1.LargeImageList = images;
listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 255);

cmd.Connection = msc;

MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    byte[] imagebyte = (byte[])(dr["image"]);
    MemoryStream image_stream = new MemoryStream(imagebyte);
    image_stream.Write(imagebyte, 0, imagebyte.Length);
    images.Images.Add(dr["image"].ToString(), new Bitmap(image_stream));
    image_stream.Close();

    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
    listItem.Text = dr["id"].ToString();
    listItem.ImageKey = dr["image"].ToString();

    listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Comment: All of your images are probably in the image list but the `ListViewItem.ImageKey` you're setting isn't referencing them. When adding images to the image list try using the `Add(string key, Image image)` overload instead, then `ListViewItem.ImageKey` should reference the same key. If your book names (`book.id`) are unique you could use that for the key, otherwise generate a row number or something to use in both places.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i don't understand what you mean?